# Convert bytes into list

Tags: python

I am new to this sort of stuff, so sorry if it's really simple and I am just being stupid.

So I have this variable with some bytes in it (not sure if that's the right name.)
data = b'red\x00XY\x001\x00168.93\x00859.07\x00'

I need to convert this to a list. The intended output would be something like.
["red","XY","1","169.93","859.07"]

How would I go about doing this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How did the \x00 end up in front of the characters?

Comment: maybe you need something like data.decode('utf-8').split() depending on your encoding

Comment: The \x00 is there because this data is coming from a separate program that is sending it over via sockets. I have no control over if the \x00 is there or not. And @Chris I've tried that. I can't seem to turn it into any sort of string. If I could I would use the split method.

Comment: What is the rule that tells you where to split up the data? What is the rule that tells you how to convert bytes into strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the following line:

```
[x.decode("utf8") for x in data.split(b"\x00") if len(x)]
```

Going part by part:

- `x.decode("utf8")`: `x` will be a bytes string, so we need to convert it into a string via `.decode("utf8").
- `for x in data.split(b"\x00")`: We can use python's built in `bytes.split` method in order to split the byte string by the nullbytes to get an array of individual strings.
- `if len(x)`: This is equivalent to `if len(x) > 0`, since we want to discard the empty string at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This code may help you to understand if you want exact same output using the `pop()` function.

```py
data = 'red/x00XY/x001/x00168.93/x00859.07/x00'  # I change "/" mark from "\" because i'm  using Linux otherwise it will give error in Linux
 
new_list = []  # There is a variable that contain empty list

for item in data.split('/x00'):  # Here I use split function by default it splits variable where "," appears but in this case
    new_list.append(item)        # you need list should be separated by "/" so that's why I gave split('/x00') and one by list appended
    
print(new_list)
```